# lightbox + imageflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, imageflow

I'm using [imageFlow](http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Examples), and now i need to activate [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) effect on the images.

Imageflow allow me to write the function onclick on each image, but how is possible to activate the lightbox effect without changing the whole script?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, how to integrate the both modules: [WordPress NextGen ImageFLow a Lightbox](http://www.kristan.eu/?p=119)

In article is a part of code, which must be added to `<head>`.